# How to correct encode a string to UTF8 in delphi10?

Tags: delphi, replace, utf-8

I am trying to replace some wildcards in a html code to send it via mailing.
Problem is when I try to replace the string with wildcard 'España$country$' with the string 'España', the result would be 'EspañaEspa?a'. I had the same problem before in Delphi 7 and I solved it by using the function 'UTF8Encode('España')' but it does not work on Delphi 10.

I have tried with 'España', 'UTF8Encode('España')' and 'AnsiToUTF8('España')'. I also tried to change the function StringReplace with ReplaceStr and ReplaceText, with same result.

```
......
var htmlText : TStringList;
......
htmlText := TStringList.Create;
htmlText.LoadFromFile('path.html');
htmlText.StringReplace(htmlText.Text, '$country$', UTF8Encode('España'),     [rfReplaceAll]); 
htmlText.SaveToFile('anotherpath.html');
......
```

This "stringreplace" along with "utf8encode" works well in Delphi7, showing 'España', but not in delphi 10, where you can read 'Espa?a' in the anotherpath.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delphi 7 `string` type, and consequently `TStrings`, did not support Unicode. Which is why you needed to use `UTF8Encode`.

Since Delphi 2009, Unicode is supported, and `string` maps to `UnicodeString`, and `TStrings` is a collection of such strings. Note that `UnicodeString` is internall encoded as UTF-16 although that's not a detail that you need to be concerned with here.

Since you are now using a Delphi that supports Unicode, your code can be much simpler. You can now write it like this:

```
htmlText.Text := StringReplace(htmlText.Text, '$country$', 'España', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Note that if you wish the file to be encoded as UTF-8 when you save it you need to specify that when you save it. Like this:

```
htmlText.SaveToFile('anotherpath.html', TEncoding.UTF8);
```

And you may also need to specify the encoding when loading the file in case it does not include a UTF-8 BOM:

```
htmlText.LoadFromFile('path.html', TEncoding.UTF8);
```